# .Net framework 3.0, 3.5 , 2.0 not showing in Visual studio 2012 only 4.0 and 4.5 in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have installed the Visual studio 2012 but its not showing lower .net framework like 3.5 , 3.0 , 2.0 in windows 8.1 OS

The visual studio 2012 is showing the framework from 4.0 - 4.5. Instead i want visual studio with framework from 2.0 - 4.5 like i got in windows 7 operating system after i installed visual studio 2012.

If i install it on windows 7 its showing all the framework. Also while installing SQL server 2008 its not getting installing and showing missing .net framework 3.5(containing 2.0 and 3.0 )

Comment: You can install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 8.1: [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 or 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh506443.aspx). It should let you use .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 in VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the .NET Framework 3.5 yourself through Control Panel. In Control Panel, choose Programs and Features, choose Turn Windows features on or off, and then select the .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) check box. This option requires an Internet connection. You do not need to select the child items for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) HTTP activation unless you are a developer who requires WCF script and handler mapping functionality.

Answer (score 4):

There is no  .NET Framework 3.5 for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 by default. You must enable them manually

from the **MSDN**  [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 or 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)