# VS19 .NET Target Frameworks is locked on 2.0, 3.0, & 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.8

I can not create a class library (or anything) above the .NET Framework versions of 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 for some odd reason. I've tried a fresh install (also running InstallCleanup.exe and cleanup up the cache's), reinstalling my workloads, packages, and SDK's, installing the target frameworks from the website and the VS19 Installer. Nothing seems to work at all!

Thank you in advance.

Available frameworks:
[image: Frameworks Being Locked]

Installed frameworks:
[image: Installed Frameworks]

Comment: hi, try to install developer pack >  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer

Comment: Open `Visual Studio Installer`. Click `Modify`. Click `Individual Components`. Select desired .NET framework versions and Targetting Packs

Comment: I've already done that and left a screenshot in the post as well, nothing works for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you have installed the .NET Framework correctly. We have to install the SDK file, but not just the targeting pack. This page shows you how to determine which .NET Framework version is installed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

If you didn't install the .NET Framework correctly, you can install the version you want manually.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework

Comment: Even though I have the .NET Framework 4.6.1 installed, it doesn't show there. Yes, I have installed everything I need correctly, manually and from the VS Installer. Quite confused why it doesn't show in the tool or VS19. https://clap.shx.gg/5f2zdOTF2.png

Comment: We have to repair the .NET Framework firstly. If it is useless we have to uninstall the framework and install again. 

This page shows you where to download the .NET Framework Repair Tool.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Comment: Just ran the repair tool and re-installed the framework, still not showing up in VS19 although it does show up in control panel as "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack (ENU)".

Comment: In order to solve the compatibility problem, please try the following operations.
First, search and open ‘turn windows features on or off’.
Second, choose the framework which you needed.
Finally, try to create a new project again.
You can also refer to these pages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126944/net-framework-3-0-3-5-2-0-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2012-only-4-0-and-4-5?rq=1

Comment: I already have the features turned on. The pages you linked are *if you don't have 3.5 enabled*, which is the issue I'm facing. https://clap.shx.gg/5fliZJ6sd.png